# how to pass filewriter object between beanshell processor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using beanshell processor in jmeter where i am defining FileWriter object in one beanshell processor and passing the object(fstream) to another beanshell processor.

```
String filename = "test.csv";
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filename , true);
props.putObject("fstream", fstream);
```

Now i am trying to get the fstream object to another beanshell processor

```
fstream = props.getObject("fstream");
```

When i am running jmeter script, i am getting following error message:

> Error in method invocation: Method putObject( java.lang.String,
>   java.io.FileWriter ) not found in java.util.Properties'

I know why i am getting this error because i m trying to pass a filewriter object but this type of function not found in properties class.
Then how should i pass filewriter object between beanshell processor, please explain and provide the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is within the bounds of one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you can go for [`vars.putObject("fstream", fstream);`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
2. If the scenario assumes different thread groups you can go for just `props.put("fstream", fstream);` function as it [assumes Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put-K-V-) already
3. There is [`bsh.shared` namespace](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) so you can share an arbitrary object via it like:

   - in 1st scripting element:

     ```
     bsh.shared.fstream = fstream
     ```
   - in 2nd scripting element:

     ```
     fstream = bsh.shared.fstream
     ```
4. Consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as this approach has much better performance comparing to Beanshell